# как настроить php mail

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Cоздал на ***apache*** сервере файл **mail.php**

```
var_dump( mail("myemail@gmail.com" ,"Test","Test") );
```

на страницу вывелось `bool(false)` 
и письмо не пришло как это можно исправить ?
и как понять где проблемам в настройках ***apache*** или в ***php***
чего то не установлено из модулей ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужно поставить почтовый сервер, например postfix, sendmail

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте себе `sendmail` а так же скачайте библиотеку для работы с почтой `PHPMailer`.
Потом в скрипте подключаете библиотеку и вот пример кода.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('mailFROM@info.ru', 'Name Name'); //от кого придет письмо
$mail->addAddress('mailTO@info.ru', 'Name2 Name2');//кому оно уйдет
$mail->addAttachment('/some/files/file.jpg');  //добавить вложение, если требуется
$mail->Subject = 'TableTask'; //тема письма
$mail->msgHTML("Some text here"); //текст письма
$r = $mail->send();
```